# How to use Global Temp View as table for join in read_sql_query - DataBricks

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

people! I'm currently trying to make some queries at Data Bricks with the pysark.pandas library, using the function read_sql_query. Whithin the same spark application, i have created some glogal temp views.

What I would like is to use this temp as table to do a left join in the read_sql_query.

Here is an example:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
con = conection_to_db

df = ps.DataFrame(data = {some_data})
df.to_spark().createGlobalTempView('temp_name')

df_query = ps.read_sql_query(sql = f'''SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM DB.TABLE AS A
LEFT JOIN global_temp.temp_name AS B on A.COLUMN = B.COLUMN''', con=con)
```

But I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'global_temp.temp_name '
```

I've tried also

```
jdbcDF3 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", con) \
    .option("query", '''SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM DB.TABLE AS A
                     LEFT JOIN global_temp.temp_name AS B on A.COLUMN = B.COLUMN''') \
    .load()
```

But gives me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?
There is a better way to join a table from a temp view to a table from the DB, with some SQL query?

We are trying to stay as close to SQL as possible, because we are migrating some SQL from SAS to Data Bricks, and therefore, the necessity to create and join temps, just like we did with SAS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "some glogal temp views." what are global temp views? Either they are views or they aren't, there is no such thing as a temp view. Is there or is there not a table or view in the schema `global_temp` called `temp_name`?

Comment: "temp views" and "global temp views" are session-scoped views in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`df.to_spark().createGlobalTempView('temp_name')`

creates a Global Temp View in your Spark Session.  This line

```
jdbcDF3 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", con) \
    .option("query", '''SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM DB.TABLE AS A
                     LEFT JOIN global_temp.temp_name AS B on A.COLUMN = B.COLUMN''') \
    .load()
```

Sends a query to SQL Server.  SQL Server knows nothing about the global temp view in your Spark session.

For SQL Server to be able to reference the data in `df` you would need to write it to SQL Server with `spark.write`.

Comment: Hi David, thaks for the answer! So, the only way to join the temp with the SQL Server query (without writing to SQL Server, because I don't have the acess to), would be using some pyspark join with `jdbcDF3` and the Dataframe from the temp (`spark.table("global_temp.temp_name")` or `spark.sql("select * from global_temp.temp_name")`)?